# Line in audio input oscilloscope

Tags: python, audio, fft, oscilloscope

I'm trying to build oscilloscope using line in Audio input and do filtering on it. I'm using python and Ubuntu.

I am able to send input to computer and read from line in audio input and record and play it.

Now I want to filter a particular frequency sin wave input at 300 Hz. How do I do that digitally ?

My guess is to use some kind of frequency filter using Fourier transform but I'm not sure.

Any help in right direction will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: There are entire textbooks on signal processing, filtering and the Fourier transform.

Answer (score 2):

An answer was given for 500Hz with JavaScript here
[Detect audio frequency from microphone with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29215531/detect-audio-frequency-from-microphone-with-node-js/33047628#33047628)
You can easily translate that to Python.